# Change Permissions with single command

Tags: unix

How would i write a single command line that will change the permissions on the file “ex: document1.txt” so that the owner has all rights, members of their group have read and write rights, and others have read rights.

Comment: This looks like a homework. As all your other questions do.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to see man (manual) pages for `chmod` (for changing permission of the file) and `chown` (for changing file's owner) Linux commands or to utilize [the websites](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwir96LdurzPAhUD6xQKHeXDDI8QFgg6MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fman.cx%2F&usg=AFQjCNEbzHgUzO7SNcbNEAxcViNn17Dq9g&sig2=kpfLVJ_vXvGd4aQ0kpOHHg) to read manuals in their "physical" absence.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `chmod` command:

```
chmod 764 "ex: document1.txt"
```

~ or ~

```
chmod u+rwx,g+rw,o+r "ex: document1.txt"
```

Both commands do the same thing. In the first command, "764" represents octal or "absolute" permissions:
'7' for read, write, execute permissions granted to 'User'
'6' for read & write permissions granted to 'Group'
'4' for read permissions granted to 'Other/World'